# Can I use LoadLibrary on Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in a design phase of a web service. I'll be using MVC 4 and we are looking at Azure. I have an unmanaged C++ DLL (32 and/or 64 bit, we can build both) that is internal, legacy code that I have to live with for now. The DLL just exports functions (no classes) that are needed by the MVC code.

Since the .NET DllImport statement is fixed regarding the DLL name, we went to a scheme in the .NET code to do a LoadLibrary via kernel32.dll. This seems to work well locally and gives the advantage to changing the DLL loaded based on 32/64-bitness and/or debug version.

1. Will this LoadLibrary approach work on Azure?
2. Where is the best place to put the library? I was thinking App_Data folder.

Comment: Should work fine on a full windows VM.

Answer (score 2):

Should work fine as long as you have the [Visual C++ Runtime Libraries](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed on the cloud side ([Instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11137282/1469494)), and the native dll's you call are compiled as 64-bit.

I don't know about the best location, I simply put the native dll inside a folder named "x64" (or x86 for 32bit) inside the folder that contains the wrapper assembly, and then just put that folder under the project root.

Also don't forget set the native dll's "Copy to output directory" property to "Copy Always".

Comment: Another option would be to have all the dependencies of the .dll statically linked into the .dll.